# Selection OnChange change PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, onchange

Hello StackOverflow People.

I need you help. I have this code:

```
<select name="type" onChange="idk?" class="form-control">
<option value="H">Week 51</option>
<option value="V">Week 52</option>
</select>
```

And if an user change the week i want to change the file get content :s

```
$Week = "";
echo file_get_contents('http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/'.$Week.'/c/c00050.htm');
```

Thanks!

**greetings from the Netherlands =)**

Comment: You need to send that selected `week` value to your server either in a AJAX call or with a simple form submit and capture the request param as $week and use it to derive your contents URL.

Comment: Do you have an example my experience with ajax is 0%

Comment: There are lot of examples in google. You need to decide first whether you want to go with AJAX or a simple form submit. If it's ok to refresh the page to get the new contents, then submit the form or send an AJAX request if otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send Ajax request to the "file_get_contents" url. 
This is what I am using and it works fine :)

```
<select name="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="H">Week 51</option>
    <option value="V">Week 52</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".form-control" ).change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            // You are not sending any post variables right? Then leave this empty :-) otherwise use it as array 'var1': 'value', 'var2': 'value2' ...
        },
        url: 'http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/'+$(this).val()+'/c/c00050.htm',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg); // Optional, show text that was given by URL, can be removed
        }
    });
  });   
});
```

[jquery.com/jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Sorry didn't work before with ajax, Do you have an example from the whole code with the selection form to? :s

Comment: You will need only jQuery for this :-)

Comment: Where is the FileGetContens?

Comment: well.. the whole Ajax is like "file_get_contents". 
"url" is the link that you need to achieve